# Apache Flink CEP Timout Pattern in not defined by time window

Tags: apache-flink, flink-cep

I am using `PatternTimeoutFunction` for discarding the event sequence when it falls out of the defined time window.

I am setting the watermark as follows

```java
public Watermark checkAndGetNextWatermark(Event lastElement, long extractedTimestamp) {
    return new Watermark(extractedTimestamp);
}
```

When pattern timeout happens, `timeoutTimestamp` should be equal to first event timestamp + value of timewindow

But timeout is triggering after receiving the next watermark. Is timeout triggered after receiving next watermark or based on `timeWindow` expiry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout is triggered by the reception of the watermarks if you use event time. Because you can only be sure to have seen all elements up to a certain point if you receive the watermark for this timestamp.

This means that the timeout timestamp can be larger than the first event timestamp + window length depending on the value of the next watermark. Thus, the timeout timestamp is actually the event time when you realize that your pattern timed out.

Comment: Should it trigger timeout if i increase the watermark time as new Watermark(extractedTimestamp + 1) ?

Comment: Depending on what `extractedTimestamp` is. If `extractedTimestamp` is the equal to `timestampOfElement + windowLength - 1`, then it should trigger.

Comment: What i observed is timeout/watermark processing is triggered only after receiving next event. I have tested having only one event, it has to timeout after window length.

Comment: Then you might not have sent a watermark after the first element. Given that a watermark which exceeds the window length arrives after the first element, you should see the pattern timeouts occurring. Could you check this?